# Excel Macro to Concatenate first and last name sometimes fails

Tags: excel, vba

I am a Visual Basic newbie. From hints on the web, I pieced together an Excel macro that does several things, including concatenating first and last name, in a loop, to make a new column with those joined. Half the time it works great, half the time I end up with no space between the first and last name. (In those cases, closing, re-opening, and re-running almost always works.) Is this a timing issue? I'll put in the whole macro but it's the Do While loop near the top that I think is the problem.

Thanks for any help.

```
Sub WholeThing()
'
' WholeThing Macro
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Name = "original"
    Rows("1:1").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Do While ActiveCell <> ""  'Loops until the active cell is blank.
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = _
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets("Original").Activate
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A1")
    Range("D1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("B1")
    Sheets("Original").Activate
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Columns("Y:Y").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    Columns("Z:Z").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")
    Columns("AA:AA").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1")
    Columns("AB:AB").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A1")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Sheet5").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Y:\Addrs_DL", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    Sheets("Sheet4").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Y:\Addrs_D", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Y:\Addrs_SL", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Y:\Addrs_S", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    Sheets("Sheet6").Activate
    ChDir "Y:\"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Y:\NAME-ADR.CSV", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
    CreateBackup:=False
 '    Application.Quit
 '    Application.ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
 '    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your source data.  Have you considered putting breakpoints into your code and stepping through?

Comment: Avoid using `ActiveCell`. Instead set the range object you want to loop through and work directly with that.

Answer (score 4):

By not using `ActiveCell` and working with your range directly, you can make your code more stable and more reliable.

Consider something like this (see notes about assumptions on range and cell references).

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("original")

With ws

     Dim lRow as Long
     lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row 'assumes first name in column B

     'assumes concatenated name goes in column A, starting at row 1 (and the first and last name are in B and C, respectively
     .Range("A1:A" & lRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1] & "" "" & RC[2]"

     'if you want to copy as values you can use this
     .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value = .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value

End With
```

You can also work with the same principles of working directly with the object later on in your code, like this:

```
'lRow would be the last row of data in the column (assumes same row for each column, based on dataset)
ws.Range("Y1:Y" & lRow).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

Doing this will save a lot of processing time as copying **entire** columns is **very** inefficient if it's not truly needed.

Comment: I will try to get my newbie head around the sample you sent. Your assumptions about where things go are correct. The data are just names, email addresses, and various flags, arranged in columns. There are about 1,000 rows.

Comment: The only later use of the Concatenated names (e.g., John Doe) is to save them to a file, along with their associated email addresses (e.g., JDoe@gmail.com). As I understand it, to save these to an external CSV file, I have to put the two columns into a separate worksheet, and save that.

Comment: Two months later and I tried out the top code, but even after changing "1Row" to "Row1" still gives an error: Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed. The highlighted line is: .Range("A1:A" & Row1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1] & "" "" & RC[2]"

Comment: Also, on the lower block of code, beginning with the comment: '1Row would be the last . . .' it would be very helpful if you, or someone else, could say where that line would go in my script--and in place of what lines.

Comment: @HarryBinswanger - Apologies. I forgot to add the `.Row` to the end of the line that sets `lRow`. See my edits. The lower block of code replaces all the copy and paste lines you have. (I just provided an example for one column).

Comment: Scott: thanks for the immediate reply! 1Row: Excel 2010 or VBA 7.0 doesn't seem to accept numbers as the beginning of variable names.

Comment: @HarryBinswanger - it's a lowercase `L`, not a `1`. You can make it whatever you want though. I use lowercase `L` for the long type.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response. Alas, neither block works yet. The concatenation block does nothing that I can see onscreen (and I have commented out Application.ScreenUpdating = False). The second block of code stops on the first iteration (column Y) and generates: Run-time Error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

Comment: @HarryBinswanger - as I noted in my answer, you may need to adjust the sheet and range references to match your exact datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

To do the concatenate, I had first to use this to get the number of the last row:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
```

That enabled this loop to do the concatenation:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("original")
With ws
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 2) & " " & Cells(i, 3)
    Next i
```

Then, for the second block (the "With ws" being still in effect):

```
Sheets("Original").Activate
    Range("Y1:Y" & LastRow).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```